# Refactoring request: Trying to find more optimal way to filter an array of objects applying several filters

Tags: javascript, filter, refactoring, reduce

Trying to filter an array of objects by the properties of another array of objects:

Data that I have

```
const filters = [
    {
        "id": "breed",
        "value": "bulldog"
    },
    {
        "id": "owner",
        "value": "Kevin"
    }
]

const dogs = [
    {
        "name": "Zephyr",
        "breed": "bulldog",
      "owner":"Kevin"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dude",
        "breed": "labradoodle",
      "owner":"Lance"
    },
        {
        "name": "Mark",
        "breed": "yorkie",
      "owner":"Rob"
    },
      {
        "name": "Cheddar",
        "breed": "bulldog",
      "owner":"Kevin"
    },
]
```

Output should be look like that:

[
{
name: "Cheddar",
breed: "bulldog",
owner: "Kevin",
},
{
name: "Zephyr",
breed: "bulldog",
owner: "Kevin",
},
];

But instead I am getting just:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Zephyr",
        "breed": "bulldog",
        "owner": "Kevin"
    }
]
```

This is what I am doing:

```
dogs.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  filters.forEach((element) => {
    if (dogs.find((i) => i[element.id].includes(element.value))) {
      if (!acc.some((e) => e[element.id].includes(element.value))) {
        acc.push({ ...obj });
      }
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), get the list of dogs meeting the filters

```js
const 
  filters = [ { "id": "breed", "value": "bulldog" }, { "id": "owner", "value": "Kevin" } ],
  dogs = [ { "name": "Zephyr", "breed": "bulldog", "owner":"Kevin" }, { "name": "Dude", "breed": "labradoodle", "owner":"Lance" }, { "name": "Mark", "breed": "yorkie", "owner":"Rob" }, { "name": "Cheddar", "breed": "bulldog", "owner":"Kevin" } ];
  
const filteredDogs = dogs.filter(dog => 
  filters.every(({ id, value }) => dog[id] === value)
);

console.log(filteredDogs);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your ans:**

```
const result = dogs.filter(dog => {
  return filters.every(filter => dog[filter.id] == filter.value)
})
```

**Code snippet**

```js
const filters = [
    {
        "id": "breed",
        "value": "bulldog"
    },
    {
        "id": "owner",
        "value": "Kevin"
    }
]

const dogs = [
    {
        "name": "Zephyr",
        "breed": "bulldog",
      "owner":"Kevin"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dude",
        "breed": "labradoodle",
      "owner":"Lance"
    },
        {
        "name": "Mark",
        "breed": "yorkie",
      "owner":"Rob"
    },
      {
        "name": "Cheddar",
        "breed": "bulldog",
      "owner":"Kevin"
    },
];

const result = dogs.filter((dog)=> {
  return filters.every((filter)=> dog[filter.id] == filter.value)
})

console.log(result)
```